# Use 0 values too in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to use the 0 on a function execution too.

For example, when a function start with 0 and a value, it will only use the values started after 0.

```
function test(X){
 console.log(X)
}
```

when executing

```
test(01)
```

it will only print "1", but no "01".

I need to use this because I'm trying to use a function with a ZIP/postal code.

Comment: why not use test('01')?

Comment: JavaScript will be just using a Numeric value when you pass in `01` you should really use strings `"01"`

Comment: Yep, that's working, thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose with '' or ""

```js
function test(X) {
  console.log(X)
}
test('01');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strings:

```
function test(X){
  console.log(X)
} 

test("01"); -> "01"
```

And if you want to conver it back to int:

```
parseInt("01"); -> 1
```